# Check proof writing of divisibility of a number by 9 in base 10 if the sum of its digits is divisible by 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

A beginner here, please give feedback on proof writing.

Proving that (the sum of the digits of a number -in base 10- being divisible by 9) $\implies$ (the number itself is divisible by 9)

Let $x=d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}...d_{n-1}d_{n}$

Our premise, $(\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{i}) \text{ mod }9=0$

On base expansion, $x=10^{n-1}d_{1}+10^{n-2}d_{2}+10^{n-3}d_{3}...+10^{1}d_{n-1}+10^{0}d_{n}$

A general term is of the form : $10^{n-j}d_{j}$, where $j \in \{1,..,n\}$

$10^{n-j}d_{j}=((10^{n-j}-1)+1)d_{j}=(10^{n-j}-1)d_{j}+d_{j}$

To prove divisibility would be to show that the base expansion of $x \text{ mod } 9 = 0$

As,

$(\sum_{j=1}^{n} 10^{n-j}d_{j}) \text{ mod }9=0 \iff (\sum_{j=1}^{n} ((10^{n-j}-1)d_{j}+d_{j}) \text{ mod }9=0 
\iff \\ (\sum_{j=1}^{n} (10^{n-j}-1)d_{j}) \text{ mod }9=0 \text{ and } (\sum_{j=1}^{n} d_{j}) \text{ mod }9=0$

As, $(10^{k}-1)c \text{ mod } 9=0$, for $k \text{ and } c\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$

Here, $(n-j) \text{ and } d_{j} \in \mathbb{N_{0}}$

Therefore, $(\sum_{j=1}^{n} (10^{n-j}-1)d_{j}) \text{ mod }9=0$

So it remains to show that $(\sum_{i=1}^{n} d_{i}) \text{ mod }9=0$, but as it was our premise, hence proved that $x \text{ mod } 9=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all correct but you can be a lot quicker. When working with modular arithmetic, if you are multiplying or adding, you can always substitute numbers so it is automatic that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n 10^{n-1} d_n \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n d_n \pmod{9}$$

(be careful when dividing because that is not well defined unless you are modulo a prime)

Comment: Thanks, I highly appreciate it.

Comment: Reminder that if you are satisfied with my answer, you should mark it as so to close the question